# Ubuntu 18.04 - GNOME Shell more than one window behaviour problem

Tags: 18.04, gnome-shell, ubuntu-dock

I installed Ubuntu 18.04 on two systems and it resulted in two different behaviours of the GNOME shell when one application has more than two Windows.

For example Firefox (wanted behaviour):
1 open Window + 2nd private window open. In the Ubuntu dock the Firefox Icon now has two dots. When clicking the Firefox Icon a little preview opens where i can choose which one to open.

[image: expected behaviour]

For some reason this doesn't work on my second installation of Ubuntu 18.04 and I couldn't find any settings regarding this. When having two windows open and clicking the icon in the dock it automatically opens the recently used Window.

I really don't want to re-install from scratch because it took me a long time setting the system up and everything else is working perfectly fine.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Open Terminal and run the following command on your second installation

```
gsettings set org.gnome.shell.extensions.dash-to-dock click-action 'previews'
```

This would provide the little preview windows you're looking for.

Comment: Unfortunately, this does not solve it for me. Is it possible that running `gsettings set org.gnome.shell.extensions.dash-to-dock click-action 'minimize'` beforehand does not allow this change?

Comment: @Ethunxxx That should not be the case, have you rebooted (or re-logged in) once after running the command?

Comment: Yes, I have, but I still does not work. I get the following message in the terminal when I run your command: `GLib-GIO-Message: Using the 'memory' GSettings backend.  Your settings will not be saved or shared with other applications.` Is that normal?

Comment: @Ethunxxx Have you logged in as the root?